# expand and collapse TextView inside ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to use expand and collapse in my android app. Every description name should be in ListView and after clicking ListView, It should expand a TextView with description and collapse again after clicking that ListView. And I have  more 10 description.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: use ExpandableListView like here: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

use `ExpandableListView` for this functionality.

Here is some tutorial

- [AndroidHive Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)
- [Tutorial2](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)

u can also see these links for more info

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html